# ArcMap repair data link to basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a map (ArcMap) that uses a basemap that is supplied with ArcMap.  The data link has been lost and, though I know how to repair a data link, I cannot find the data for the ArcMap basemap.

I have a screenshot here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/frydzj604zeglxy/arcmap%20screenshot.JPG?dl=0

Does anyone know where ArcMap is hiding these data files....or how I might repair the link without having to rebuild the map from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

They are traditionally located in the templates geodatabase:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb

be sure to correct for your version (10.0)

Right click on one and do the traditional fix.